# Cумма квадратов нечетных цифр в числе

Tags: python

> Дано число, введенное с клавиатуры. Определите сумму квадратов нечетных цифр в числе.

```
N=int(input("Введите натуральное число N:"))
print(N)
total=0
for i in ???:
    if i%2==0:
        continue
total=total+int(i*i)
print(total)
```

Как брать цифры из числа? isdigit?

Что я должен вставить на то место, где я поставил три знаки вопроса?

Или не так решать?

Добавление:

```
N=int(input("Введите натуральное число N:"))
print(N)
total=0

for i in map(int, str(N)):
    if int(i)%2==1:
        print(i)
        continue
    total=total+(int(i)**2)

print(total)
```

Comment: *>Что я должен вставить на то место, где я поставил три знаки вопроса?* - `for i in map(int, str(N)):`.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов: Спасибо!

Comment: Ввожу число 12345, а сумма выходит 20, а не 35. Не пойму почему

Comment: Без кода можно только гадать, что у Вас там. Если в коде из текущего вопроса вместо вопросов подставить `map(int, str(N))` и добавить отступ перед `total=total+int(i*i)`, то Вы получите желаемый результат.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов: Добавил код. Не пойму что с ним не так.

Comment: Ну правильно. `if int(i)%2==1: ...; continue` - Вы же теперь пропускаете **не**чётные цифры и в итоге получаете сумму квадратов чётных цифр числа.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример:

```
N = 12345              # считаем, что пользователь ввёл это число
sum_squared_odd = 0    
while N > 0:
     N, d = divmod(N, 10)
     if d % 2:
         sum_squared_odd += d**2

print(sum_squared_odd)
# 35
```

---

также можно преобразовать число в строку и итерироваться по строке:

```
sum_squared_odd = 0
for d in str(N):
    d = int(d)
    if d % 2:
        sum_squared_odd += d**2

print(sum_squared_odd)
# 35
```

Answer (score 4):

```
n = input()
print(sum([int(i)**2 for i in n if int(i) % 2]))
```

Comment: лист внутри sum не надо, генератор просуммируется

Answer (score 1):

Однострочник:

```
print(sum(int(i)*int(i) for i in input() if int(i)%2))
```

Comment: Ну это практически не отличается от другого ответа, только учтен комментарий и `input` внутрь перенесён

Comment: @CrazyElf это так, но еще тут используется непосредственное умножение вместо оператора возведения в степень, что ускоряет работу.